# How do I make a django model exclusive to another model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Keg and Floor model

```
class Keg(models.Model):
    tapped = models.BooleanField('Tapped')
    beer = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Floor(models.Model):
    kegs = models.ManyToManyField(Keg)
```

How do I make the keg model exclusive to the floor, meaning if I create a floor with a keg I don't want to be able to create another floor with that keg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a many-to-one relation; that is, a floor can have many kegs, but a keg can only be on one floor.

In Django that is represented by a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey). For example:

```
class Keg(models.Model):
    tapped = models.BooleanField('Tapped')
    beer = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    floor = models.ForeignKey("Floor")

class Floor(models.Model):
    pass
```

Comment: Though now it is an object of the Keg class, and I can still only select one Floor. Sorry if I am misunderstanding. I would like to be able to select multiple kegs for each floor but not allow the kegs to be on any other floor.  With your solution do I need to specify something else?

Comment: @butteredpopcorn: I'm not sure what you mean by *select*. Are you talking about an SQL `SELECT`, or selecting objects with your mouse in the admin, or something else? If you have a `Keg`, you access its (single) `Floor` with `keg.floor`. If you have a `Floor`, you access its (multiple) `Kegs` with `floor.keg_set`. See the [documentation on related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).

Comment: I guess I am just confused about defining the backwards relationship from Floor to Keg. I want to be able to edit the Floor kegs on the Floor admin page. How would I define the class Floor to do this?

Comment: @butteredpopcorn: There's an example of this in [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#adding-related-objects), and a detailed description in the [admin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects). If you're still confused, I suggest creating a new question specifically about the admin.

Answer (score 1):

Use OneToOneField field. Documentation for [One-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

```
class Floor(models.Model):
    keg = models.OneToOneField(Keg)
```

Comment: Actually this was not what I wanted, I want to be able to select multiple kegs, but the kegs that are selected unavailable for other floors.